# jquery cookie plugin save multiple value in same name

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, wordpress, cookies

I'm trying to save data into cookies but i want to store multiple value in same cookie name like an array i'm using

```
 jQuery('.addToCartBtn').on('click', function (ev) {
            var ProductId = $(this).attr('rel');
            if($.cookie('product_id') != ProductId){
                $.cookie('product_id', [ProductId] , {expires: 1, path: '/'});
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Strongly suggest using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) rather than cookie. Keep in mind that every single request to server (images, css, data, script files, html etc) will have to send that cookie.

Parse it as JSON string

```
JSON.stringify(ProductId);
```

And back

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product_id')); //or $.cookie('product_id');
```